# What is forcing indescribability?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Suppose $m, n\in\omega$ and $\kappa$ is a cardinal. Then $\kappa$ is *$\Pi^m_n$-indescribable* if every $\Pi^m_n$-sentence true about $\kappa$ is true about some $\lambda<\kappa$; formally, if for every $\Pi_n$-sentence $\varphi$ in the language of set theory with a unary predicate and every $A\subseteq V_\kappa$, there is some $\lambda<\kappa$ such that $$(V_{\kappa+m}, \in, A)\models\varphi\implies (V_{\lambda+m}, \in, A\cap V_\lambda)\models\varphi.$$ For example, the $\Pi^1_1$-indescribable cardinals are exactly the weakly compact cardinals. (Note that we can go beyond $\Pi^m_n$-describability - [quite a ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrewd_cardinal), even - but let's ignore that for now.)

I'm interested in a version of indescribability where we pay attention to what can happen in generic extensions of $V$ (I don't think this really qualifies as a "generic" version indescribability, but there's a vague connection). Specifically, for an ordinal $\alpha$ and a set $C\subseteq V_\alpha$, write "$(V_\alpha, \in, C)\models_f\varphi$" if $((V_\alpha)^{V[G]}, \in, C)\models\varphi$ for every $G$ which is set-generic over $V$ (note that the forcing for which $G$ is generic need *not* be an element of $V_\alpha$). Now say that a cardinal $\kappa$ is *$\Pi^m_n$-forcing indescribable* if for every $\Pi_n$-sentence $\varphi$ in the language of set theory with a unary predicate and every $A\subseteq V_\kappa$, there is some $\lambda<\kappa$ such that $$(V_{\kappa+m}, \in, A)\models_f\varphi\implies (V_{\lambda+m}, \in, A\cap V_\lambda)\models_f\varphi.$$ *Note that $A$ is a fixed set in the ground model.*

My question is, roughly how "big" are the forcing-indescribable cardinals? For example, it is not clear to me what the relationship is between $\Pi^1_1$-indescribable (= weakly compact) cardinals and $\Pi^1_1$-forcing indescribable cardinals. I believe that *in $L$*, $\Gamma$-forcing indescribability implies $\Gamma$-indescribability (since we can replace $\varphi$ with "$\varphi$ holds in $L$"), but I don't see the converse, or how this holds in general $V$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to somehow mess things up just by collapsing $V_{\kappa+m}$ to be countable?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In what way? Even if $V_{\kappa+m}$ is countable, $(V_{\kappa+m})^{V[G]}$ will have lots of interesting structure . . .

Comment: Consider the name for the generic for the collapse of $V_\kappa$ to be countable. This is a subset of $V_\kappa$, so it's fine. Now state that this is a generic name for a surjection from the natural numbers onto the universe. Try to reflect that after forcing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But the statement "$A$ is a name for a surjection from the naturals onto the universe" *isn't* true in all forcing extensions of $V$ ($A$ doesn't change but $V_\kappa$ does), so $V_\kappa\not\models_f$ it.

Comment: Right. Do you even have some non-trivial examples of $\varphi$ such that $(V_\kappa,\in,A)\models_f\varphi$? (And by non-trivial I mean avoiding things like $V\neq L$ or something like that.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do in fact! Consider this relation on countable structures $A$ and $B$: "Every copy of $A$ with domain $\omega$ computes a copy of $B$." (This is *Muchnik reducibility*. All languages are finite.) We write "$A\le_wB$". We can make sense of $\le_w$ for uncountable structures: say "$A\le_w^*B$" if $A\le_wB$ in every generic extension where both $A$ and $B$ are countable. This is something [I and others](http://www3.nd.edu/~gigusa/papers/Igusa-Knight-Schweber-Submitted.pdf) have looked at; for example, one easy fact is that $(\omega_1, <)\le_w^*(\mathbb{R}, +, \times)$. (cont'd)

Comment: Incidentally, the indescribable cardinals are also naturally generalized by the strongly unfoldable cardinals, which directly generalize the embedding characterization of indescribability, rather than the reflection characterization as you have.

Comment: Now the point is that by construction, "$\le_w^*$" is forcing absolute (and indeed we can replace "every generic extension" with "some generic extension" and leave the definition unchanged); so if e.g. $A, B$ are possibly uncountable structures in $V_\kappa$, and $V_\kappa$ thinks $A\le_w^*B$, then so does $(V_\kappa)^{V[G]}$ for every generic extension $V[G]$. (There are of course other examples of such statements, but this  is a class I've been thinking about recently.)

Comment: @Joel: If I remember correctly, every reflection property can be described via embeddings instead; and I think there is even a reference to that in the comments or answers somewhere on this very site (perhaps in the question I had asked about weakly compact cardinals?).

Comment: Noah, thanks. That is interesting. I don't know if I'd call this entirely non-trivial, but it is not a trivial statement indeed. I'll sit this one out, since I've got no good suggestions for now. :)

Comment: Yes, Asaf, and I've written about that connection at length in several papers. My point is that one should mention the strongly unfoldable cardinals as generalizing the indescribable cardinals transfinitely.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Wait, so is it non-trivially trivial? :D (I mean, it's certainly trivial in one sense - it's an immediate corollary of Shoenfield absoluteness. But in a different sense, $\le_w^*$ seems interesting, so it's not stupidly trivial - or rather, its triviality doesn't stupidify it. (I should stop typing now.))

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for the info, I was unaware of this! The connection you and Asaf mention sounds very cool - what's a good paper to start reading about this?

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1133077 seems like a good place to start?

Comment: Here are a few: http://jdh.hamkins.org/indestructiblestrongunfoldability/,  http://jdh.hamkins.org/unfoldablecardinals/, http://jdh.hamkins.org/diamondcanfail/. And there are more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start things off by providing an upper bound. The bound is
very large, however, and I expect that it can be improved, perhaps
dramatically. But at least it shows the consistency of your large
cardinal relative to some other well-studied large cardinals.

**Theorem.** If $\kappa$ is $1$-$C^{(2)}$-extendible, then it is
forcing $\Pi^m_n$-indescribable for every $m,n$.

**Definition.** A cardinal $\kappa$ is
[$1$-$C^{(2)}$-extendible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_cardinal),
if there is an elementary embedding $j:V_{\kappa+1}\to
V_{\theta+1}$, with critical point $\kappa$, such that the target
$j(\kappa)=\theta$ is $\Sigma_2$-correct in $V$, meaning
$V_\theta\prec_{\Sigma_2} V$.

This is a fairly strong large cardinal notion, far stronger than
the totally indescribable cardinals you mention in your question.
For example, every 1-extendible cardinal is superstrong and much
more. But these cardinals are weaker than Vopěnka's principle.

**Proof.** Assume that $\kappa$ is $1$-$C^{(2)}$-extendible. So
there is an elementary embedding $j:V_{\kappa+1}\to V_{\theta+1}$
with critical point $\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)=\theta$ is
$\Sigma_2$-correct in $V$.

Suppose now that $A\subset V_\kappa$ and $\langle
V_{\kappa+m},\in,A\rangle\models_f\varphi$, which means that
$\langle V[G]_{\kappa+m},\in,A\rangle\models\varphi$ for every
forcing extension $V[G]$. This is a $\Sigma_2$ property about $A$
and $\kappa$, since any violation of it would be revealed inside
some large enough $V_\eta$, using forcing inside that $V_\eta$.

Thus, by $\Sigma_2$-correctness, we see that $V_\theta$ agrees that
$\langle V_{\kappa+m},\in,A\rangle\models_f\varphi$. Since
$A=j(A)\cap\kappa$, we may pull this back by elementarity to
conclude that there is some $\lambda<\kappa$ with $\langle
V_{\lambda+m},\in,A\cap V_{\lambda+m}\rangle\models_f\varphi$
inside $V_\kappa$. But $\kappa$ itself must also be
$\Sigma_2$-correct, and so actually $\langle
V_{\lambda+m},\in,A\cap V_{\lambda+m}\rangle\models_f\varphi$ in
$V$, as desired. **QED**

I'll think some more about lower bounds and about pulling down the
strength of the hypothesis.

**Update.** I've realized that we can improve the upper bound as
follows. We don't really need the "$+1$", since that actually
provided a uniform version of the phenomenon, with the same
embedding working for every $A$.

Thomas Johnstone and I defined that a cardinal $\kappa$ is
*uplifting*, if it is inaccessible and $V_\kappa\prec V_\theta$ for
cofinally many inaccessible cardinals $\theta$. (J. D. Hamkins, T.
Johnstone, [Resurrection axioms and uplifting
cardinals](http://jdh.hamkins.org/resurrection-axioms-and-uplifting-cardinals/))
A boldface version is that $\kappa$ is *strongly uplifting*, if for
every $A\subset V_\kappa$ there are cofinally many inaccessible
cardinals $\theta$ for which $\langle
V_\kappa,\in,A\rangle\prec\langle V_\theta,\in,A^*\rangle$ for some
$A^*\subset V_\theta$. (J. D. Hamkins, T. Johnstone, [Strongly
uplifting cardinals and boldface
resurrection](http://jdh.hamkins.org/strongly-uplifting-cardinals-and-boldface-resurrection/))
These have diverse equivalent formulations, as I mention on the
linked blog post, connected with strengthenings of the strongly
unfoldable cardinals.

Let me now strengthen this a little more, for the present
application, with the following new large cardinal concept.

**Definition.** A cardinal $\kappa$ is *strongly
$C^{(n)}$-uplifting*, if for every $A\subset V_\kappa$ there is a
$\Sigma_n$-correct cardinal $\theta$ and $A^*\subset V_\theta$ with
$\langle V_\kappa,\in,A\rangle\prec\langle
V_\theta,\in,A^*\rangle$.

This is what we really needed in the theorem above.

**Theorem.** If $\kappa$ is strongly $C^{(2)}$-uplifting, then it
is forcing $\Pi^m_n$-indescribable for every $m$ and $n$.

**Proof.** Argue as in the first theorem above, but now we have
only $\langle V_\kappa,\in,A\rangle\prec\langle
V_\theta,\in,A^*\rangle$, instead of $j$. If $\langle
V_\kappa,\in,A\rangle+m\models_f\varphi$, then this will be true
inside $V_\theta$ since it is $\Sigma_2$-correct, and so $V_\theta$
thinks that this holds on an initial segment of $A^*$, and so we
get $\lambda<\kappa$ with $\langle V_\lambda,\in,A\cap
V_\lambda\rangle\models_f\varphi$ inside $V_\kappa$, which is right
about this since $\kappa$ is itself $\Sigma_2$-correct. **QED**

I think the strongly $C^{(2)}$-uplifting cardinals are
comparatively weak, and absolute to $L$, but I'll think more about
it.

Comment: That Wikipedia article is really annoying in switching between "extendible" and "extensible" arbitrarily. Sometimes even in the same sentence.

Comment: I think it is not arbitrary, but is using that difference to indicate $\forall\eta$. I hadn't seen this usage much before, but it cites Kanamori for it.  Is that usage in Kanamori? I always just call them "extendible" rather than "extensible".

Comment: I don't think "extensible" appears in Kanamori, and it really the last two anonymous edits that introduced that. In any case, I think that it's terrible grammar to switch from US to UK spelling of the same word in the middle of the sentence...

Comment: If that is true, I think it should be edited back to "extendible."

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Re: lower bounds, I've been thinking and I can't even show that every $\Pi^1_1$-forcing indescribable cardinal is weakly compact. Am I missing something, or is this indeed nontrivial? If it is nontrivial, do you know the answer? (I would *love* it if the least $\Pi^1_1$-forcing indescribable can consistently be much lower than the least weak compact.)